# How to place nav.link to the right react-bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, navbar

I am trying to place the last Nav.Link (logOut) to the right on the nav bar (see picture) without affecting the other nav.links. I have tried with d-flex and so on but it does not work. What to do in the specific nav.link for getting it to stay right, and still included in the Navbar.collapse?

```
import "./NavBar.css"
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
export const NavBar = () =>{
    return (
<Navbar className="nav-bar" expand="lg" sticky="top">
  <Container>
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Scancar</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
     <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav"> 
      <Nav className="ml-auto">    
          
            <Nav.Link href="find">Find booking</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="book">Book</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="pricing">Overview</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="pricing">Release</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="pricing">Request</Nav.Link>    
            <Nav.Link href="logOut"> <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> </Nav.Link>     
            
      </Nav>

    </Navbar.Collapse> 
   
  </Container>
</Navbar>    
   
    );
}
```

[See the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krvAb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ms-auto`

```
<Nav.Link href="logOut" className="ms-auto"> <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> </Nav.Link>
```

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/layout/stack/?#horizontal

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It aligns the nav.link to the right when I use the toggle after the navbar collapse. But before the collapse the nav.link is in the same place as before. I also need it to the right when it is a big screen.

Comment: Ok, You can try to remove `ml-auto` on Nav and replace by `w-100`